# SpringBoot app in Docker not connecting to MySQL db

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

MySQL process is up and accessible, but Spring is not able to connect and stops:

```
 java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Docker-compose is like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_demo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: demo
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  spring-rest-api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: rest_api
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/demo?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PWD: secret
      DB_NAME: demo
    volumes:
      - ./data/applogs:/tmp/logs
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
```

I can connect to MySQL container and from inside the container I can connect to MySQL.
From the host PC I can't but I think it's a problem with MySQL client inability to connect over tcp (or I can't do it).

Anyway, SpringBoot is starting correctly but can't get a connection and then crash.
Without Docker the application works normally.

I noticed in the logs also

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
```

I'm a bit blocked...

Comment: just found &allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true and added to the url...it seems to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was self-explanatory. After some search, I found the parameter that needed to be added to the data source URL

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/ny_database?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

Inside a docker-compose I also had to change the localhost to this

```
services:
 ....
 restapi:
 ....
   environment:
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldocker:3306/my_database?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
 ....
 mysqldocker:
 ....
```